# Update Case Record based on Webservice Callout

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, case

We have an email2case implementation, where a 3rd party system takes care of the routing, one of the inputs this needs is to determine the language of the email that has been received to ensure that the correct agent gets the case.

As ServiceCloud doesn't have inbuilt language detection for the cases we have implemented a Webservice callout that calls a 3rd party language detection API. This callout works as expected, however, we cannot hook this up to the initial case creation as seemingly Web service callouts are not permitted on triggers.

Currently we are trying to implement this with a combination of Process builder, flow and Apex, its setup as:
- Process builder triggers on case creation, sets a scheduled task that runs 1 hour before Creation date (usually this then runs in 1-2 minutes). The scheduled task is a flow
- The flow then calls the InvokableMethod wrapper from the Webservice Callout
- Gets the detected language (or error) and updates the case subject with it (purely for testing)

However, the error returned is 'You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out'

Invokable method:

```
public class DetectLanguageAction {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<string> UpdateCaseLanguage(List<Case> cases){

        List<string> languageResults = new List<string>();

        for (Case cas : cases){

            string bodyText = cas.Description;
            if(cas.Description.Length()>500){
                bodyText = bodyText.substring(0,500);
            }

            string detectedLanguage = DetectLanguage.detect(bodyText);

            languageResults.Add(detectedLanguage);
        }

        return languageResults;
    }
}
```

Language Detection class:

```
    public class DetectLanguage
{
    private static final String ENDPOINT_URL = 'http://ws.detectlanguage.com/0.2/detect';
    private static final String TEXT = 'q[]=';
    private static final String AMP = '&';
    private static final String API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX';
    private static final String POST = 'POST';
    private static final String ERR = 'ERROR: ';
    private static final String STATUS_OK = 'OK';

    public class LanguageDetectionResult
    {
        public Decimal confidence;
        public Boolean isReliable;
        public String language;
    }

    public static string detect(string bodyText){  
        string defaultLanguage = 'Not Identified';

        if(bodyText =='') 
          return 'No text input';          

        String webServiceBody = 'q=' + bodyText;

        HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        req.setMethod(POST);
        req.setEndPoint(ENDPOINT_URL);
        req.setBody(webServiceBody);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + API_KEY);

        List<LanguageDetectionResult> detectionResults = new List<LanguageDetectionResult>();
        try
        {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(req);


            if (response.getStatus() == STATUS_OK)
            {
                System.debug(response.getBody());
                Integer counter = 0;
                JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());

                while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
                {
                    if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) 
                    {
                        while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
                        {
                            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) 
                            {
                                detectionResults.add((LanguageDetectionResult)parser.readValueAs(LanguageDetectionResult.class));
                            } else if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY)
                            {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    parser.nextValue();
                }
            }               
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.debug(ERR + e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        } 

        if(detectionResults.isEmpty()){
            System.Debug('No Detection results present');
            return 'No results returned';
        }

        for(LanguageDetectionResult result : detectionResults){
            system.debug('Confidence:' + result.Confidence.toPlainString() + ' Language: ' + result.Language);
            if(result.isReliable && result.confidence > 10){
                return result.language;
            }
        }

        System.Debug('No reliable detection results present');
        return 'No reliable result';        
    }
}
```

Flow:
[image: Flow overview]

Apex Action call:
[image]

Flow assignment step:
[image: Assignemnt step]

Current result:

[image: Current Result]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Sounds like the case record is not committed to DB yet and you are trying to perform an update on it. Just for the sake of testing, could you remove the last element in the flow (Update Records) and check if you are still running into this error??

Comment: Hi Arut, this was really helpful, you are spot on the problem wasn't actually the visible DML but how salesforce passes information in from a process builder to a flow

Comment: Glad my suggestion helped you. I was suspecting that the transaction was not yet committed to the DB while the flow is executing. BTW, good write up on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was actually that when the Flow is triggered from a process builder (even on a schedule), SF appears to open a transaction and therefore considers a DML pending and Webservice callouts not supported.

In my specific scenario I needed to make a web service call and then do a data update using the response. If you just needed to do the webservice call you can just mark your APEX as @Future and this will run async.

In my situation I did the following:

- Create a Platform Event on Case Creation
- Create a Process Builder that is triggered by the creation of a
  platform event, that calls the flow
- Flow as below gets Language Returned from Callout
- Updates case after that

[image: Final Flow]

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you can't have a DML operation interrupted by a callout. This is a design limitation that prevents excessively long row locks on the database. From where you are, it would probably be easiest to just add a Pause between the Start and Get Records elements. The Pause will delay the callout until after the trigger completes.

Side note: There's a method you can use instead of substring:

```
String bodyText = cas.Description == null? null: cas.Description.abbeviate(500);
```

You do need to check for null before checking a string's length anyways to avoid a NullPointerException. The abbreviate method won't error on strings shorter than the requested limit, though, so it can save an extra check.

Comment: So the steps here are:
- Process builder triggers on case create, no immediate actions
- Schedule action put in for (1hr before creation date) that calls the flow, this usually runs like 1-2mins later.

The case would be committed at this stage no?

Comment: @OCDan Yes, that shouldwork as well. You need to just get out of the current insert transaction.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, thats how it is currently implemented. I can't see how that is still within a transaction?